# Is there a way to hide form items that already exist in the database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, antd

```
const AddPartQuestionModalAgain = ({
    isModalVisible,
    hideModal,
    questionData = {
        question_no: '',
        question_parts: [''],
    },
}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    let formInput
    console.log(questionData)

    return (
        <>
            <Modal
                visible={isModalVisible}
                onCancel={() => {
                    formInput.resetFields()
                    hideModal()
                }}
                width={1200}
            >
                <Form
                    layout='vertical'
                    ref={(ref) => {
                        formInput = ref
                    }}
                    name='dynamic_form_item'
                >
                    <Form.List name='question_parts' key='question_parts'>
                        {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                            <>
                                {fields.map((field, index) => (
                                    <Space
                                        key={field.key}
                                        direction='vertical'
                                    >
                                        <Form.Item key={`QuestionPart${index}`}>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col span={10}>
                                                    <div
                                                        style={{
                                                            overflow: 'auto',
                                                            height: 400,
                                                            width: 590,
                                                        }}
                                                    >
                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            {...field}
                                                            label={`Question Part ${index + 1} Description`}
                                                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'part_desc']}
                                                            name={[field.name, 'part_desc']}
                                                            key={`part_desc${index}`
                                                        >
                                                            <Input.TextArea
                                                                rows={8}
                                                                placeholder='Description'
                                                            />
                                                        </Form.Item>
                                                        <Form.Item
                                                            {...field}
                                                            label={`Question Part ${index + 1} Marks`}
                                                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'part_total_marks']}
                                                            name={[field.name, 'part_total_marks']}
                                                            key={`part_total_marks${index}`}
                                                            
                                                        >
                                                            <Input
                                                                placeholder='Marks'
                                                                style={{
                                                                    border: '1px solid black',
                                                                    width: 450,
                                                                }}
                                                            />
                                                        </Form.Item>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Col>
                                                <div class='vl'></div>
                                                <Col span={12} offset={2}>
                                                    <div
                                                    >
                                                        <Form.List
                                                            {...field}
                                                            name='part_guided_answer'
                                                            fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'part_guided_answer']}
                                                            name={[field.name, 'part_guided_answer']}
                                                            key={`part_guided_answer${index}`}
                                                        >
                                                            {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                                                                <>
                                                                    {fields.map((field, index) => (
                                                                        <Space
                                                                            key={field.key}
                                                                            direction='vertical'
                                                                            
                                                                        >
                                                                            <Form.Item key={`QuestionPart${index}`}>
                                                                                <Form.Item
                                                                                    {...field}
                                                                                    label={` Question Part  Guided Answer ${
                                                                                        index + 1
                                                                                    }`}
                                                                                    fieldKey={[
                                                                                        field.fieldKey,
                                                                                        'part_model_ans',
                                                                                    ]}
                                                                                    name={[field.name, 'part_model_ans']}
                                                                                    key={`part_model_ans${index}`}
                                                                                    
                                                                                >
                                                                                    <Input.TextArea
                                                                                        rows={4}
                                                                                        placeholder='Guided Answer'
                                                                                    
                                                                                    />
                                                                                </Form.Item>
                                                                                <Form.Item
                                                                                    {...field}
                                                                                    label={`Question Part 
                                                                                
                                                                                 Guided Answer Marks ${index + 1}`}
                                                                                    fieldKey={[
                                                                                        field.fieldKey,
                                                                                        'part_answer_mark',
                                                                                    ]}
                                                                                    name={[
                                                                                        field.name,
                                                                                        'part_answer_mark',
                                                                                    ]}
                                                                                    key={`part_answer_mark${index}`}
                                                                                
                                                                                >
                                                                                    <Input
                                                                                        placeholder='Guided Answer Marks'
                                                                                        
                                                                                        }}
                                                                                    />
                                                                                </Form.Item>

                                                                                <MinusCircleOutlined
                                                                                    className='dynamic-delete-button'
                                                                                    
                                                                                    onClick={() => remove(field.name)}
                                                                                />
                                                                            </Form.Item>
                                                                        </Space>
                                                                    ))}
                                                                    <Form.Item style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                                                                        <Button
                                                                            type='dashed'
                                                                            onClick={() => add()}
                                                                            icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                                                                        >
                                                                            Add Question Part Guided Answer
                                                                        </Button>
                                                                        <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                                                                    </Form.Item>
                                                                </>
                                                            )}
                                                        </Form.List>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Col>

                                                <MinusCircleOutlined
                                                    className='dynamic-delete-button'
                                                    onClick={() => remove(field.name)}
                                                />
                                            </Row>
                                            <div class='vr'></div>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Space>
                                ))}
                                <Form.Item>
                                    <Button
                                        type='dashed'
                                        onClick={() => add()}
                                        icon={<PlusOutlined /
                                    >
                                        Add Question Part
                                    </Button>
                                    <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
                                </Form.Item>
                            </>
                        )}
                    </Form.List>
                </Form>
            </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

The above code basically gives me this picture below
[image]
what I would like to do is hide the items that already exist which is in the blue circle and only show items without anything inside and I would also like to have it so that it resets every time I open it because right now(see picture below) even if there is nothing inside it shows me this
[image]
that's because in my database my table for these values are null
| Question_id |part_id       | part_desc | part_model_ans|answer_mark|
| ------------|--------------|-----------| --------------|-----------|
|10           | null         | null      |  null         |null       |
|10           | null         |null       |  null         |null       |

Answer (score 0):

you can  hide it like this, Since you can count the string of the text, In your case the text will be coming from server right

```
return (<div>
{firstname.length > 0 ? null: <p>FirstName</p> }
{secondName.length > 0 ? null: <p>secondName</p> }
{thirdName.length > 0 ? null: <p>thirdName</p> }
</div>)
```